# How to combine values from RDD set?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, set

If i have an `RDD[(Int, Array[Boolean])]`, how could i combine the values from each set?

E.g.

If my `RDD` is:

```
(1, Array(true, false, true)) (2, Array(true, true, false))
```

I want as result:

```
(1, Array(true, true, true)) (2, Array(true, true, true))
```

Comment: What do you want to do? By your example is hard to know what is it. Convert all to true? Explain that better please so we can help you.

Comment: What you seem to be doing is a "bit-wise or" between the two arrays. The problem is that that your two arrays have a different partition key (or at least I assume the first element of the tuple is a partition key) and they may not be present on the same machine. What would you want to do if there were 100 different partition keys?

Comment: you need to consider doing this using spark sql and window functions on dataframe instead of using RDD

Comment: Yes, `bitwise or` is what i want, and i know that there are different keys and that a possible solution would cause shuffle, but i want a compination of the values of the sets to be the new value for each key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand this correctly, you want all records in the RDD to have the same *value*, with that value being the array of results of bitwise OR operation on each index of the arrays.

In that case, you can start with a `reduce` action to compute this single value, and then map the original RDD into a new one with this new value for all records:

```
val newVal = rdd.values.reduce((a1, a2) => a1.zip(a2).map { case (b1, b2) => b1 | b2 })
val result = rdd.mapValues(_ => newVal)

result.mapValues(_.toList).foreach(println) 
// prints:
// (1,List(true, true, true))
// (2,List(true, true, true))
```

Note that this solution ignores edge cases like empty input or unequal array sizes.